# Constructor not returning method

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

I keep getting catchPhrase is not a function. I'm trying to figure out why it isn't logging.When I use the other methods on that's included in my code it works, but this specific one isn't working.

```
function Humanoid(humanoidAtts) {
  GameObject.call(this, humanoidAtts);
  CharacterStats.call(this, humanoidAtts);
  this.faction = humanoidAtts.faction;
  this.weapons = humanoidAtts.weapons;
  this.language = humanoidAtts.language;
}

Humanoid.prototype = Object.create(CharacterStats.prototype)

Humanoid.prototype.greet = function(){
  return `${this.name} offers a greeting in ${this.language}`
}

 function Hero(heroAtts) {
   Humanoid.call(this, heroAtts);
 }

 Hero.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype);
 Hero.prototype = Object.create(CharacterStats.prototype);
 Hero.prototype = Object.create(Humanoid.prototype);

 Hero.prototype.catchPhrase = function(){
  return `${this.name} says, look you got blood on my dress`
}
```

Hero is defined further down.

```
const hero =  new Humanoid ({
  createdAt: new Date(),
  dimensions: {
    length: 3,
    width: 2,
    height: 5,
  },
  hp: 20,
  name: 'Bouncing Betty',
  faction: 'Tot Land',
  weapons: [
    'Parasol',
    'Tessen',
  ],
  language: 'Tabaxi',
});

console.log(hero.catchPhrase());
```

Comment: You're reassigning `Hero.prototype` three times - all but the last get GC'd immediately.

Comment: You have not defined `hero`.